# Prevent Beautiful Soup from closing my tags

Tags: php, python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I import a header and footer with PHP in which I close the head, start and close the body, and close html.  Like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<?php include ('Header.php');?>
CODE
<?php include ('Footer.php');?>
```

Beautiful soup tries to fix this by inserting tags to fix my 'broken' ones.

```
<html>
<head>
<?php include ('Header.php');?>
</head><body> <-------------------------
CODE
<?php include ('Footer.php');?>
</body></html>  <-------------------------
```

I know Beautiful Soup is working as intended, but how can I either remove the added tags, or make Beautiful Soup not add them. I've tried the lxml parser but it did the same exact thing.  Thanks.

Comment: I think the ideal would be open and close a tag in the same scope.
Even for a better readability and future debugging

Comment: Well I close the head and start the body in the Header PHP.  Then I close the body and html in the Footer PHP.  I would have to create two separate Header PHPs and close the head and open the body inbetween the two.

Comment: Couldn't find a way to do it, so I took Marcos' advice and put all the HTML tags in the html.  I had to create an extra PHP include, but that's alright.

Answer (score -1):

What parser are you choosing when you call BeautifulSoup?

Try using the Python default parser:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(your_html, 'html.parser')
```